# how do you use custom colors on google gauge chart with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

i've created a function in apps script that pulls data from one google sheet (`sht_data`) and serves up a gauge chart in another google sheet (`sht_charts`).

```
function new_renewable_gauge() {
  var range = sht_data.getRange('B16:C16');
  var chartBuilder = sht_data.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(range)
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.GAUGE)
      .setPosition(1, 7, 1, 1)
      .setOption('title', 'renewable % of committed generation')
      .setOption('yellowFrom', 50)
      .setOption('yellowTo', 70)
      .setOption('greenFrom', 70)
      .setOption('greenTo', 100)
      .setOption('minorTicks', 5);
  sht_chart.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

pulling and presenting the data works fine, no issues. where i get stuck is setting colors other than `green` / `yellow` / `red` for the shaded areas on the gauge. what i want to use is the gradients of green in the google palette, i.e. light green 3 (40-60) / light green 1 (60-80) / dark green 2 (80-100).

i've tried searching the net for how to define theses colors... no joy. things i've tried:

- initially i tried `.setOption('lightGreenFrom', 40).setOption('lightGreenTo', 60)` but the chart returned white space
- setting the colors first `.setOption(colors, [lightGreen, green, darkGreen])` on a COLUMN chart first to see if it will accept the color names; only `green` was accepted
- numerous ways of writing those colors (`lightgreen3`, `lightGreen3`, `light-green-3`, `light-green3`, `light_green_3`, `light_green3`) with a COLUMN in case there was a specific way of writing those names; not recognized

any help that the community can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share a spreadsheet with some dummy data and an example gauche chart?

Comment: hi @albertovielma, not sure what the purpose is of your request. the above function contains everything for rendering the chart except for the content of `B16:C16` which is `'utilization': 80`. the utilization number is determined by an API call which i can't share unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

according to the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge#configuration-options),
to change the actual colors,
you can use the following options --> `'greenColor', 'yellowColor', 'redColor'`

as for the color values,
you'll need to find the html hex values of the names.
e.g.

```
.setOption('greenColor', '#c8e6c9')
.setOption('yellowColor', '#4caf50')
.setOption('redColor', '#1b5e20')
```

here is a pallette, originally developed by google...

https://htmlcolorcodes.com/color-chart/material-design-color-chart/

Comment: thanks for sharing the pallette. so if i understand this correctly, the color regions will always be red / yellow / green but you can use `.setOption()` to display as a different color.